# Need to take snapshot of running application in x11

Tags: x11

We need to take snap shots of running application by clicking a button in X11. We used XCopyArea function and copied the current image in a Pixmap. we need a way that how to same as image file in hard disk. Please help us. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a toolkit that has this functionality built in. Qt, Gtk, wx all have it. You can roll your own function to convert from pixmap to say PNG, but this is a rather tedious job that is already done by somebody else.

Comment: Thank you, we are using only X11 programming not Qt, Gtk, wx. So we need answers in X11.

Comment: So you want to know how to write a Pixmap to a file?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the Pixmap to a file using:

```
int XWriteBitmapFile(Display *display, char *filename, Pixmap bitmap,
              unsigned int width, unsigned int height, int x_hot, int y_hot);
```